# Difference between Bitcoin versions 0.1 and 0.2

Tags: bitcoin-core

Does anybody know what the difference is between Bitcoin versions (0.1) and (0.2)?
I need to know this because I am doing a school project about the future of Bitcoin.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in a list of changes to Bitcoin, look at these sources:

- 0.3.21 - current: https://bitcoin.org/en/version-history
- 0.1.0 - 0.3.20: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoind#History_of_official_bitcoind_.28and_predecessor.29_releases
  (Click on the reference to see the announcment/changelog.)

Good luck with your project!